# Retrieving an AFC Image field

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if anyone can provide a solution for a problem I am having getting an afc image field to display on my web page. I have added a custom field and uploaded the image but calling the image just isn't working. My code is as follows...

```
<?php

        $i = 1;     
        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4);    
        $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

        if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
            while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
                $category_posts->the_post();

                $link = get_the_permalink();
                $feat = get_field('home-image',$post->ID); 
                $paw = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'featured-thumb');
                $paw2 = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'featured-thumb'); 
                $paw3 = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'featured-thumb');

                if ($i === 1) {
                    echo '<div class="featured-article"><a href="'.$link.'"><h2>Our latest news & events</h2><div class="tag-title"><div class="feat-tag">FEATURED</div><h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3></div>'.$feat.'</a></div>';
                }
                else {
                    if ($i === 2) {
                        echo '<div class="small-container">';
                    }
                    if ($i == 2) {
                        echo '<div class="one-third small-blog-item article-'.$i.'"><a href="'.$link.'"><div class="paw">'.$paw2.'</div><h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3></a></div>';
                    }
                    if ($i == 3) {
                        echo '<div class="one-third small-blog-item article-'.$i.'"><a href="'.$link.'"><div class="paw">'.$paw.'</div><h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3></a></div>';
                    }
                    if ($i == 4) {
                        echo '<div class="one-third small-blog-item article-'.$i.'"><a href="'.$link.'"><div class="paw">'.$paw2.'</div><h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3></a></div>';
                    }
                    if ($i === 4) {
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                }

                $i++
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you really need to pass 2 parameters in get_field('home-image',$post->ID)?

Comment: The loop calls up the latest 4 posts. How else could I identify which post I want the uploaded image to be displayed for without using the $post->ID parameter?